# Trying to filter only digits in string array using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to filter only digits in string array. This works if I have this array:
12324 asddd 123 123, but if I have chars and digits in one string e.g. asd1234, it does not take it.
Can u help me how to do it ?

```
int[] result = input
            .Where(x => x.All(char.IsDigit))// tried with .Any(), .TakeWhile() and .SkipWhile()
            .Select(int.Parse)
            .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: Try `input.ToCharArray()....etc`

Comment: Give more info, for example: what would you do if find a string like aaa123aaa123?

Comment: only the digits, in the string aaa123aaa123 i want only the digits, so the output...something like 123123

Comment: Why you have this: ` .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)` you want to pick the even numbers?

Comment: yes, that's part of the task

Comment: Your `input` is a `string` or `string[]`? You want your array of single digits or contiguous digits to be combined in a number?

Comment: string[] , I want array of only digits, if input is asd123 124 444as, I want output like this: 123 124 444

Comment: You can exclude non digit chars from the string with regexp like so: `var digitOnlyString = Regex.Replace(y, "[^0-9]", string.Empty);`. The output will be an empty string if there were no digits in the string, or just a string with all digits from your input. Use `TryParse` to get the result. Take a look at my answer here with `Aggregate()`, it works as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. The function `digitString` will select only digits from the input string, and recombine into a new string. The rest is simple, just predicates selecting non-empty strings and even numbers.

```
var values = new[]
{
    "helloworld",
    "hello2",
    "4",
    "hello123world123"
};

bool isEven(int i) => i % 2 == 0;
bool notEmpty(string s) => s.Length > 0;
string digitString(string s) => new string(s.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());

var valuesFiltered = values
    .Select(digitString)
    .Where(notEmpty)
    .Select(int.Parse)
    .Where(isEven)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in 2 steps: First filter out all the invalid strings, then filter out all the non-digits in the valid strings.

A helper Method would be very readable here, but it is also possible with pure LINQ:

```
var input = new[]{ "123d", "12e", "pp", "33z3"};

input
  .Where(x => x.Any(char.IsDigit))
  .Select(str => string.Concat(str.Where(char.IsDigit)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq Aggregate method and TryParse() can give you perfect result:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var input = new string[] { "aaa123aaa124", "aa", "778", "a777", null };

var result = input.Aggregate(
    new List<int>(),
    (x, y) =>
    {
        if (y is null)
            return x;
            
        var digitOnlyString = Regex.Replace(y, "[^0-9]", string.Empty);

        if (int.TryParse(digitOnlyString, out var temp) && temp % 2 == 0)
            x.Add(temp);

        return x;
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Possible null values should be drop to avoid `NullReferenceException`.
2. `string.Join()` suitable for concatenation with digit filtering.
3. Additinally empty texts should be dropped because it cannot be converted to an integer.

```
string[] input = new string[] { "1234", "asd124", "2345", "2346", null, "", "asdfas", "2" };
int[] result = input
      .Where(s => s != null)
      .Select(s => string.Join("", s.Where(char.IsDigit)))
      .Where(s => s != string.Empty)
      .Select(int.Parse)
      .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
      .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Max,

You can do this in a single expression like so:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
        
var input = new[] { "aaa123aaa124", "aa", "778", "a777", null };
var rx = new Regex(@"[0-9]+");

var numbersOnly = input.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && rx.IsMatch(s))
     .Select(s => string.Join("", rx.Matches(s).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value)));

foreach (var number in numbersOnly) Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Which returns:

```
      123124
      778
      777
```

Answer (score 0):

> if I have chars and digits in one string e.g. asd1234, it does not take it

Apparently you want to parse this line also. You want to translate "asd1234" to "1234" and then parse it.

But what if your input sequence of strings contains a string with two numbers: "123asd456". Do you want to interpret this as "123", or maybe as "123456", or maybe you consider this as two numbers "123" and "456".

Let's assume you don't have this problem: every string contains at utmost one number, or if you have a string with more than one number, you only want the first number.

In fact, you only want to keep those string that are "zero or more non-digits followed by one or more digits followed by zero or more characters.

Enter [Regular Expressions!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

```
const string regexTxt = "\D*\d+.*";
Regex regex = new Regex(regexTxt);
```

- \D: any non-digit
- *: zero or more
- \d: any digit
- +: one or more
- . any character
- (...) capture the parts between the parentheses

So this regular expression matches any string that starts with zero or more non-digits, followed by at least one digit, followed by zero or more characters. Capture the "at least one digit" part.

If you try to `Match()` an input string with this regular expression, you get a `Match` object. Property `Success` tells you whether the input string is according to the regular expression.

The `Match` object has a property `Groups` which contains all Matches. Groups[0] is the complete string, Groups[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) contains a `Group` which has the first captured string in property `Value`.

A simple program that shows how to use the regular expression:

```
const string regexTxt = @"\D*(\d+).*";
Regex regex = new Regex(regexTxt);
var lines = new string[]
{
    String.Empty,
    "A",
    "A lot of text, no numbers",
    "1",
    "123456",
    "Some text and then a number 123",
    "Several characters, then a number: 123 followed by another number 456!",
    "___123---456...",
};
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    Match match = regex.Match(line);
    if (match.Success)
    {
         string capturedDigits = match.Groups[1].Value;
         int capturedNumber = Int32.Parse(capturedDigits);
         Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", line, capturedNumber);
    }
}
```

Or in a LINQ statement:

```
const string regexTxt = @"\D*(\d+).*";
Regex regex = new Regex(regexTxt);
IEnumerable<string> sourceLines = ...
var numbers= sourceLines
    .Select(line => regex.Match(line))      // Match the Regex
    .Where(match => match.IsMatch)          // Keep only the Matches that match
    .Select(match => Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
                                            // Finally Parse the captured text to int
```